# No repeating values in mysql table, but some echoed values are repeated

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make something that echoes out the url of a list of tags for playlists.  Allow me to show my mysql table (called apple_music):

```
ID | URL              | Tags
---+------------------+------------------------------
 1 |https://ex1.com   | Drake, Big Sean, Kanye West,
---+------------------+------------------------------
 2 |https://ex2.com   | Lil Pump, The Weeknd,
---+------------------+------------------------------
 3 |https://ex3.com   | Meek Mill, Drake,
```

So, each playlist url has a number of tags that go along with it. In my function, since these tags are first stored as strings, they are converted into an array, and the last element is taken off (basically, the addition of a comma and space adds an empty element at the end of each array).  After this, a user can search for ideal tags, which also be converted to an array, then compared to the stored arrays.  My function works, but if two playlist urls have a common tag, such as "Drake", then the urls are repeated.
My code looks like this:

```
        $uploaded_tags = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT tags FROM apple_music");
        while($tag_array = mysqli_fetch_array($uploaded_tags)) {
            $uploaded_tags_array = explode(", ", $tag_array['tags']);
            array_pop($uploaded_tags_array);
            $searched_tags_array = explode(", ", $tags);
            array_pop($searched_tags_array);
            foreach($searched_tags_array as $value) {

                if(in_array($value, $uploaded_tags_array)) {
                    $result = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT * FROM apple_music WHERE tags LIKE '%$value%'");
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        echo $row['url'] . "<br />";
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

If the tag "The Weeknd" is searched for, then the correct output will be displayed: 
`https://ex2.com`

However, if "Drake" is searched for, then this will be output:

```
https://ex1.com
https://ex3.com
https://ex1.com
https://ex3.com`
```

I have tried using DISTINCT and GROUP BY, but they do not work.  Any ideas?

Comment: you should not store  comma separated  values ..but build a proper relational table  between unrl and tag

Comment: I know my table design isn't the best, but I'm not worried about that right now.  I just want to know how to fix duplicate values that are echoed.

Comment: The foreach is the reason it’s being echoed  twice, since the Drake is in both ex1 and ex2. Move the while block out of foreach.

Comment: Ok, I will try it right now, thanks.

Comment: @Vikram Palakurthi I can't just move my while loop outside the foreach because it only works after the results from the foreach are obtained.

Comment: Never mind, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your query. It's working fine. The issue is in your foreach loop. It's running twice for the same tag.

```
SELECT * FROM apple_music WHERE tags LIKE '%$value%'
```

Comment: Please check loop.

Comment: @Gufram Hasan I am aware that my problem lies in my foreach loop, but I am not sure what to change it to, since it does partially work.

Comment: Did you find out solutions? If not. Can I do effort?